# Is it possible to run a print() inside a method without the @staticmethod attribute?

Tags: python, python-3.x, methods, static-methods

I come from a .NET and Javascript background and I'm working my way up to learn Python (for Raspberry Pi). 
Right now I'm trying to figure out OOP in Python and the use of methods and classes. But having a little issue with @staticmethod

```
class Car(object):
    """description of class"""

    def __init__(self, make, model):
        self.make = make
        self.model = model

    @staticmethod
    def makeFirstNoise():
        print("Vrooooommm!")

    def makeSecondNoise():
        print("Mweeeeeeeeeh!")
```

This is how I implement my class and try to run both methods.

```
from Car import Car

mustang = Car('Ford', 'Mustang')
mustang.makeFirstNoise()
mustang.makeSecondNoise()
```

This is the output:

`Vrooooommm!
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Dev\T\PythonHelloWorld\PythonHelloWorld\PythonHelloWorld.py", line 5, in <module>
    mustang.makeSecondNoise()
TypeError: makeSecondNoise() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given`

So question, why can't I execute the second method without my staticmethod attribute? This seems to work if I just return the text directly like this:

```
def makeSecondNoise():
    return "Mweeeeeeeh!"

print(mustang.makeSecondNoise())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason `makeSecondNoise` is causing an error is because it is automatically passed one argument, `self`, because it's not declared as a `staticmethod`. `self` is the instance of the class that the function was called on. This is ultimately causing the error because `makeSecondNoise` isn't coded to accept any parameters; it'd be like doing this:

```
def something():
    ...
something("Foo")
```

Here's an example of how `self` works:

```
>>> class Car:
...     def makenoise(self):
...         print(self)
...
>>> mustang = Car()
>>> mustang.makenoise()
<__main__.Car object at 0x0000000005498B38> # We can see that "self" is a reference to "mustang"
```

Your problem isn't related to `print` (I couldn't get your example without `print` to work either) - it's related to the automatic passing of the `self` argument.

Answer (score 1):

In Python all method calls (besides classmethods and staticmethods) explicitly passed object instance as first argument. Convention is to name this argument `self`. This explicit argument should be included in method signature:

```
class Car(object):
    def makeSecondNoise(self):  # note that method takes one argument
        print("Mweeeeeeeeeh!")
```

After that you may call your method without any problems.

```
mustang = Car('Ford', 'Mustang')
mustang.makeSecondNoise()
```

In Java, `this` (which represents instance object) is passed implicitly to methods - this is a source of your confusion.